# Does Go (golang) actually permit unicode characters in variable names?

Tags: unicode, go

Or is that a myth? <s>Can't see it mentioned in any official documentation</s> (it's there, D'oh!) – it sure doesn't seem to work for me when using Atom with the go-plus package. It's a shame as I am doing a lot of math operations, and I love mathematic notation.

Update: I don't consider any mathematical symbol as esoteric: ‖ ⏋∪
Compared to any emoji:

A yes or no answer with a reference to an official source would be sufficient for a tick!

Update: Thanks to elithrar's answer, I found 'Latin letter lateral click' ǁ to be a seemingly perfect analogue to 'Double vertical line' that I wanted.

Comment: Myth?! Which part of [the spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Source_code_representation) is unclear about this?

Comment: @KerrekSB Yep, see I knew I had read it somewhere, but why isn't it working? Maybe it's just the go-plus package, keeps saying it's an 'illegal character'.

Comment: @BenjaminR: We don't know what you tried to do or just what error message you saw. Please update your question with that information.

Comment: Note that "part of the UTF-8 set" isn't a good measure of support: there are multiple versions of the spec, and *many* categories (ASCII being one of those, Cyrillic another, etc). Most programming languages with UTF-8 support usually restrict identifiers to a short list of categories.

Comment: I'll take the -1 on the question, because believe me, there will be thousands of others who will google 'golang utf characters in variables' or some equivalent. I deserve to be punished for being lazy, no doubt.

Comment: For the record, this is now a "notable question". You can either despair at this, or accept that maybe my asking it wasn't so unreasonable as first thought.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go supports *some* of the Unicode categories as per https://golang.org/ref/spec#Identifiers

> Identifiers name program entities such as variables and types. An identifier is a sequence of one or more letters and digits. The first character in an identifier must be a letter.
>
> ```
> identifier = letter { letter | unicode_digit } .
> ```

The above classes are defined in the spec as:

> ```
> unicode_letter = /* a Unicode code point classified as "Letter" */ .
> unicode_digit  = /* a Unicode code point classified as "Decimal Digit" */ .
> ```
>
> In The Unicode Standard 6.3, Section 4.5 "General Category" defines a set of character categories. Go treats those characters in category [Lu](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Lu/list.htm), [Ll](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Ll/list.htm), [Lt](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Lt/list.htm), [Lm](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Lm/list.htm), or [Lo](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Lo/list.htm) as Unicode letters, and those in category [Nd](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nd/list.htm) as Unicode digits.

The 'short' answer is that *some* operators are supported, depending on their character class. The more esoteric/specialist ones won't be.

Answer (score 7):

**Yes**. I've been programming for a few months in a mix of Japanese and English. All types in my project are two characters long.

Example:

```
type T型 struct{}; //model      (literally: mold/model)
type T示 struct{}; //view       (literally: show      )
type T師 struct{}; //controller (literally: master    )
```

The antithesis of "clean code". The idea is that your brain is better at
parsing short and concise variable names.

Also, when creating a new problem domain, variable names get out of hand.
Imagine we are programming a new thing. It is milled oats mixed with water, a sweet crystalline substance, and then heat treated in a hot box for 35 minutes.

Variable Name:
HeatTreatedMilledOatsWithWaterAndSweetCrystal

Yeah, we could just call it cake. But no one has invented cake yet.

Or we could just:

```
//Literally: 食=="Meal". 
//In Code  : 食=="Heat Treated Milled Oats,Water,And Sweet Crystal"
type T食 struct{};
```

Comment: Woah there satan!

Comment: I love this. I long to go back to the days of writing code just for myself and nobody else.

Comment: Username checks out

Answer (score 2):

Why not
ľubozvučná_slovenčina := 3

works, althoght it is not good for other programmers, who don't understand this language.

Comment: ...wich isn't an issue if all your programmers understand this language.